# Cannot connect Kindle Fire HD to Windows 7 x64 machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers, kindle

I have a Kindle Fire HD which I am trying to connect to a Windows 7 x64 machine via USB.

Whenever I connect the device I get this...

[image]

I can't find any drivers for the Kindle, so I'm not sure what I need to do (or what I'm doing wrong).

Can anyone advise?

Comment: There are no drivers, it should work, so the problem likely isn't the Kindle.  Try a different pc with x64.

Comment: Or a different port in the same pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might sound basic, but I'd do a little troubleshooting with the USB port itself if you haven't already:

- Try connecting a different USB device (mouse, keyboard, etc) to that same USB port to see if they work properly
- Try connecting the Kindle to a different USB port if available, or free up a known working USB port to see if it connects properly to that one

If those are still no help, you can also follow the troubleshooting steps Amazon lists here:  http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_k6trouble_usb?nodeId=200729330#usb

One last thing to try is running Microsoft's automatic fix for malfunctioning hardware devices here:  http://support.microsoft.com/mats/hardware_device_problems